# API Connect - Published Product not visible in Developer Portal, but no errors?

Tags: apiconnect

I am not able to see the products I publish in API Connect in the APIC Developer Portal. There is no error in the logs either.

I am able to do other things on the Dev Portal, such as create new app, subscribe to existing APIs, etc.

And later, I can see this new app/subscription in API Manager.

How can I resolve such problems, like: where could I find more information about errors, etc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please navigate to https://datapower_ip/organizationName/sanboxName. I Think you are publishing to the different sandbox and searching in another. If you publish APIs via API connect management console all the APIs will be published in the developer portal(if configured in settings of sandbox)

Thanks
Srikanth